# Action in handlebars template not firing

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, dom-events

I have the following simple code:

(JSFiddle) http://jsfiddle.net/aR2UX/3/

The action in the template will not fire no matter what I do.  I'm suspicious it's due to the way the view is rendered, but no matter what I read, I can't wrap my head around it.

I'm still trying to understand ember views, but from what I've read my code in the fiddle should work.  It doesn't seem to though, can anyone help me?

(This is in a rails 3.2 app, using ember-rails, ember 0.9.4 and the handlebars template gem, btw).

Any help is greatly appreciated as I took a bit of a risk on ember for this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the handlebars templates don't have names, they are inserted into the DOM at the point they are declared – this is why you see anything at all.

This:

```
{{#each content}}
{{view Skills.RecommendedSkillView skillBinding="this"}}
{{/each}}
```

Doesn't do anything for you since `content` is not defined at this point and the handlebars template is not associated with the view.

Likewise:

```
Skills.RecommendedSkillsListView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'app/templates/recommended_skills_list',
```

Doesn't help you since `templateName` is pointing to a non-existant handlebars template, and the view classes are never instantiated (otherwise you would get a warning of a missing template).

Furthermore:

```
<td><a href="#" {{action "a"}}>DO A THING</a></td>
```

Will not call the function `a` since again this template is just inserted once in the DOM where it is encountered and `a` is not defined in that context (neither is `skill`).

And finally, when you do get your code closer to work the way you intend, there will be a problem with that every handlebars template is, by default, wrapped in a `div`. Hence your table will have `div` around every `tr`. This is solved by changing the `tagName`: http://emberjs.com/#toc_36

Comment: I was in the midst of reworking this example when you posted your explanation, Martin. Here's a greatly simplified working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dgeb/VAx6v/

The action helper changed behavior between 0.9.4 and 0.9.5. event.preventDefault() is now called by default, and the jQuery event object is no longer passed in as an arg. Instead, the view object is. My example shows how this can be used. Anyway, time to update the ember docs again...

Comment: Thanks Dan and Martin.  I actually do have named templates - am using ember-rails with handlebars and this compiles each template to its own JS file, but I don't think I was clear enough about this in my question.  Everything else in my app was working, but not the action.  I upgraded to 0.9.5 and removed the preventDefault() call though, and everything began behaving as expected.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

This doesn't answer the OP's original problem, but it fits with the title, and if you have this problem, then search engines point you to this page. Here is one possible reason why actions might not fire: the tag might not be within the Ember Application's rootElement. So if you have JS

```
FooApp = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement:"#foo",
  test: function() {
    alert("testing");
  }
});
```

and handlebars

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<a {{action "test" target="FooApp"}}>Fail</a>
```

Then nothing will happen. Had me baffled for hours.

Comment: Thanks you! It help! I made Ember.Application.create({rootElement:"body"). All events start work.

Comment: It really saved a lot of my time! Thank you! I have a view to be appended to the DOM tree dynamically, but previously no 'action' was fired. My fix is to theView.appendTo(App.rootElement) and it worked nicely!