# scoping of an action helper within a handlebars #each loop

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I've become confused about the scoping within an {{#each}} block.

If I have the handlebars script

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
      {{#each vars}}
      <button {{action foo}}> {{name}} </button>
      {{/each}}
</script>
```

and I set my application controller as

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    vars: Ember.ArrayController.create({
        content: [
            {   name: "Cow",
                foo: function(){console.log("moo");}
            },
            {   name: "Cat",
                foo: function(){console.log("meow");}
            }
        ]
    })
});
```

The script can see `{{name}}` just fine and puts it in as the title of the button as you'd expect, but action does not get bound to the  `foo`  functions defined within the array members.

Is there are way to do this that I'm missing, or do I need to refactor to make `foo` be defined directly within `ApplicationController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up an event on `ApplicationController` and pass in the individual object and call the stored `foo()`. Inside of the `{{#each vars}}...{{/each}}` block you can use `this` to pass the actual object to the event handler.

**JS:**

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    vars: Ember.ArrayController.create({
        content: [
            {   name: "Cow",
                foo: function(){console.log("moo");}
            },
            {   name: "Cat",
                foo: function(){console.log("meow");}
            }
        ]
    }),
  doFoo: function(obj) {
    obj.foo();
  }
});
```

**Handlebars:**

```
{{#each vars}}
      <button {{action doFoo this}}> {{name}} </button>
{{/each}}
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/adedag/62/edit)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, was just trying to understand whether that was completely necessary.

Comment: You can also get rid of the `Ember.ArrayController` and just set `vars` as an array.  I think you can't use `{{action}}` on those internal `foo` methods because they are not views, controllers, or routers which can accept events...

Comment: you can loop over an array, but you can't add to it later, so I'm just in the habit of using ArrayControllers

Comment: You should be able to add/modify them. Ember modifies the default `Array` and adds mixins that extend its functionality, so you can use `pushObject` and other helpers to modify the arrays in ways that Ember can keep track of for bindings.

Answer (score 0):

[Action in handlebars template not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479437/action-in-handlebars-template-not-firing)

This may be due to the root element, check this posting here for more information